# How can I send and receive email for mailgun?

Tags: email, mailgun, rackspace-cloud

Is there some kind of GUI tool or interface I can use to send and receive email for Mailgun?

https://mailgun.com

Hi, I read whole documentation but don't understand how do I use Mailgun? is there any body who can tell me how can i use mailgun its really important please help me guyz.... –

Comment: Hi, I read whole documentation but don't understand how do I use Mailgun? is there any body who can tell me how can i use mailgun its really important please help me guyz....

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer depends on how you want to send and receive email. Mailgun is built for transactional email, so if you're looking to use it for sending and receiving personal email, that might not be the best fit.

If you want to use mailgun as your SMTP relay for sending transactional mail from your site, you might want to try one of these guides from Rackspace, Mailgun's parent company:
https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/28/t/3897
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/introduction-to-mailgun-email-automation
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/configuring-mailgun-for-your-website

The TL;DR is that you need to sign up for a Mailgun account, verify your domain, and configure your application to use Mailgun as the SMTP relay.

Additionally, if you're building an application from scratch, you can incorporate the Mailgun API to send email directly. Instructions are available in the Mailgun Quick Start guide: https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart.html

Hope that helps.